# Connect PHP 7.4 to Firebird database: could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

I'm following the [docs](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fbdevgd30/firebird-30-developers-guide.html#fbdevgd30-php-drivers)  to connect php to firebird database. I activated the extension in php.ini

```
;extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

I restarted apache on xampp, and I copy pasted the code of the docs for testing. when I run the code
I get `could not find driver`

what am I missing here?

environment:

- XAMPP with PHP 7.4
- Windows 10

Comment: Do you actually have the pdo_firebird.dll on your system? Did you install the Firebird client library (fbclient.dll) of the right bitness on your system (that is if PHP is 64-bit, you need the 64-bit fbclient.dll, if it is 32-bit, then the 32-bit fbclient.dll?

Comment: Correction, the php_pdo_firebird.dll. If you go to http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php, what does it say under "PDO_Firebird"? Also, what code are you trying to execute?

Comment: For reference, I installed XAMPP, uncommented the `extension=pdo_firebird` line in php.ini, created a modified version of [this example](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fbdevgd30/firebird-30-developers-guide.html#fbdevgd30-php-drivers-pdo-connxn) (my modification changed the database, the table and the referenced column) and it worked. I however, do have a 64-bit fbclient.dll on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your installation is missing the Firebird native client library, fbclient.dll. Assuming you have installed a 64-bit XAMPP (I think that is the only option available), you need to download the [Windows 64-bit Firebird installer](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/#Win64), and use it at minimum to install the Firebird client library.

If you actually want to connect to a Firebird Server on the same system (assuming you didn't install the 32-bit Firebird Server instead), you can install the full server (which will also install the client).

After installing fbclient.dll, you need to stop and start Apache through the XAMPP Control Panel.

You can verify if the driver is loaded properly - assuming you still have the default pages in htdocs - by going to http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php, it will list the driver under "PDO_Firebird", together with the version of fbclient.dll, if the driver was successfully loaded.

Comment: I had firebird 2.5 installed on my system up and running, but it is 32bits...
Thanks to you now I tried installing the version 3.0 which is 64bits (like my php), it gave me the right dll file. When i asked the team about that, they told me to go back to the 2.5 32bits version, so i uninstalled the 3.0, and reinstalled the 2.5 32bits version.
but i think i kept the dll file of the 3.0 version, because in php info it shows `WI-V6.3.6.33328 Firebird 3.0`. PHP connection to firebird is working now. but i want to know if this is going to make any issues later or not?

Comment: should I go back to 32bits PHP? is there a way to keep my 64bits PHP and connect it to the 2.5 32bits Firebird? i'm really confused right now.

Comment: @wassimchaguetmi You can use the 32-bit Firebird just fine, but you will have to install the 64-bit client library (either from Firebird 2.5, or from Firebird 3) to be able to connect from 64-bit PHP. Given you now have the 64-bit Firebird 3 client library installed, you're good to go.